# Query working in home but not working in other page (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have 2 pages: **home.blade and listpost.blade**

This is simple query for menu **navbar.blade**:

**$query = category::where('enable', '=', ENABLE_CATEGORY);**

It's work in **home.blade** but it doesn't work in **listpost.blade**. Although both pages use **@include(navbar)**.

---

This is **HomeController (return view home.blade) and ListPostController(return view listpost.blade)**. Both use that query but only HomeController (return view home.blade) is working. In ListPostController, use category::all() is working, but where() is not working.

Why and how to fix that?

[home.blade and listpost.blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Bgr.jpg)

[Query in service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIHFt.jpg)

Comment: Where are you defining ENABLE_CATEGORY? Is it because the variable doesn't exist or isn't set to the same as it is in the other blade? You should really perform these queries in the controller and pass the results to the views.

Comment: ENABLE_CATEGORY = 1 and it's working in home.blade

Comment: And what if you replace ENABLE_CATEGORY with 1 in both blades. Do they both work then?

Comment: I was replace and only home.blade is working. listpost.blade is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I assume both of the blades have different values for `ENABLE_CATEGORY`.

The point of the controller in an MVC framework is to talk to the models and send the appropriate data to the views (the blades). Your views should not be talking to the database and fetching data.

Try something like this:

**BaseController.php**

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
    protected $ENABLED = 1;
}
```

**HomeController.php**

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function show()
    {
        $categories = Category::where('enable', $this->ENABLED);
        return view('home')->with('categories');
    }
}
```

**ListController.php**

```
class ListController extends BaseController {
    public function show()
    {
        $categories = Category::where('enable', $this->ENABLED);
        return view('listpost')->with('categories');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried and still not fixed. I replace ENABLE_CATEGORY with 1 and only home.blade is working. ENABLE_CATEGORY = 1 in constants.php

Comment: Can you post code for your home, listpost and navbar blades please?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I forgot `@extends('news.master')`

In `master.blade.php`

```php
@include('news.block.navbar')
@yield('content')
```

In `listpost.blade.php`

```php
@extends('news.master')
@section('content')
@endsection
```